# Override not-found exception handler in micronaut

Tags: java, netty, micronaut

I'm trying to override the `not-found` exception handler in micronaut.

I want to throw my custom error format, but cannot find which exception handler I've to replace.

My current implementation:

```
@Produces
@Singleton
@Requires(classes = {Exception.class, ExceptionHandler.class})
//@Replaces(NotFoundExceptionHandler.class)
public class MyNotFoundExceptionHandler implements ExceptionHandler<Exception, HttpResponse<?>> {
    
    @Override
    public HttpResponse<?> handle(HttpRequest request, Exception exception) {
        return HttpResponse.notFound();
    }

}
```

The default micronaut exception handler throws this format on a `not-found`:

```
{
    "message": "Page Not Found",
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "/api/not-found",
            "templated": false
        }
    }
}
```

I'm already overridden other default exception handlers, like `ConstraintExceptionHandler` and `UnsatisfiedRouteHandler`, but for the `not-found` the logger doesn't print the exception in the console:

```
20:43:23.863 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] DEBUG i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Request GET /api/not-found
20:43:23.864 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] DEBUG i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - No matching route: GET /api/not-found
20:43:23.864 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-5] DEBUG i.m.web.router.RouteMatchUtils - Route match attribute for request (/api/not-found) not found
```

Anyone knows which exception handler to override?

Answer (score 0):

you can find what you are looking for here https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-error-handling-maven-java.html#global-error

With this code in any controller you should be ok:

```java
@Error(status = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, global = true)
fun notFoundHandler(request: HttpRequest<*>): HttpResponse<JsonError> {
    return HttpResponse.status<JsonError>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(JsonError("Page '$request' Not Found"))
}
```